# What is the least prime containing the digitsequences 00..99?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The least prime containing all the digits 0..9 is

10123457689

What is the least prime containing all the digitsequences 00..99 in its
decimal representation ?

An example is the following prime

90857538987448099100142069586773625665168849454643928372159340471326170782412763
3505522311819603029791

with 102 digits.

Comment: If I were so inclined (which I'm not), I would write a computer program to enumerate all the numbers satisfying the requirements in increasing order and then check them for primeness until I found one. So the more interesting question is: How do you generate this sequence?

Comment: You can't go much smaller as it takes at least 101 digits to produce all 100 two-digit combinations

Comment: I wrote a PARI-program and produced various random numbers, restricting that any sequence occurs at most 2 times, and after some tries, I got this candidate.

Comment: *The least prime containing all the digits $0..9$ is* $10123457689$ - Are you sure it's not $01234576891$ ? :-) *What is the least prime containing all the digitsequences $00..99$ in its decimal representation ?* - $001122334455667788991$ ? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beat this (101 digits):
12343820246621009119671503254485735539522606365680728479308616498759414276974588313377899290518170401

Improvement:
11254572024662100919681305234473853359322606563670827489507616497839414286984377515588799290317180401

... and
10234352248821200911987160326445673663962808386850725479305818495769414278974655313377599290615170401

(Edit after being accepted) This just in, and there's still some room:
10023436224882120711785190329446953993792808389860526457306818476597414258754966313355677270916150401

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there isn't one starting with 10. Or even 10012… Primes are plentiful, after all. (I suppose starting one with a zero would be considere cheating.)

Comment: This is probably not the smallest. Since I was too lazy to find a Hamilton path, I merely permuted the digits of the OPs example ($9\to0, 0\to 1, 8\to 2, \ldots$) and played with the last digit (as "91" was double in the original). So in a way I did start with a zero but was lucky that the cheated 01 appeasr at the end.

Comment: The way I think of it, you'd be looking for an Eulerian path, not a Hamiltonian one (the nodes are the digits, and there is a directed path in each direction between any two nodes, plus one from each node to itself). To find the smallest candidate, start with a 1, then greedily pick the smallest next digit you can without repeating yourself. After a while, you also need to avoid 1 in order to be able to leave that node. The last digit will be a 1, though. The harder problem, assuming this is not prime, is to find the second smallest, and so on.

Comment: Um … after a while, you will even have to avoid nodes that will eventually force you to land at 1 too early. Perhaps better to emulate the existence proof for Eulerian paths: Follow the greedy algorithm until you have a loop ending at 1 and no way out, then cut into the loop as close to the end as you can, and repeat. But if you have to cut early, the greedy choices after that will bite you … this is not as easy as I imagined.

Comment: How do you find these?

Comment: Zafer, if you want I can share my C++ program written using GMP library.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen You are right. There is an improved answer

Answer (score 2):

I realize that the answer has been accepted but ...

This is probably the smallest

10011202130314041505160617071808190922324252627282933435363738394454647484955657585966768869778799891

Found traversing the path through all the nodes. The values were searched in ascending order and unless there is a bug in my code, this is probably the smallest.